# Action-Menu missing

Tags: plone, action-menu

I'm using Plone 4.0.1 and I have the problem, that the action menu is missing. When I want to change the state of a site or copy/paste via "actions...", I just get to the page which is linked at this button, which is folder_contents for "actions". So I can not use any of the actions.
When I investigate it with Firebug, I see this:

```
<dl id="plone-contentmenu-actions" class="actionMenu deactivated">
```

So I wonder, how can I activate the action-menu again? Sadly, I do not know what could have caused the problem.

Thanks for any help in advance,

Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much for your help! I found the problem... and I'm quite ashamed I didn't think of this before. The script "dropdown.js" in portal_javascripts has to be activated for the actionmenu to work. I do not know why it was deactivated, but now everything works :)

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

The `deactivated` class is referred to the expansion state of the menu (when you expand the menu, that class is switched with `activated` via javascript). The problem here is that you miss all 'actions' inside that menu. I see these two options:

- If you have the permission to access the zope managment interface then go to:
  zmi -> portal_actions -> object_buttons and check if buttons are "visible".
- if you do not have that permission probably someone has removed your roles/permissions to edit contents or you are not the owner of that content.

Comment: I have full access to zope, and all the buttons are visible. I still do not see the actions, even at my own content. Could it have something to do with javascript? I have javascript enabled, but maybe the relevant library is deactivated or something?

Comment: no, actions are not loaded via js, they are already in the html. In the firebug console do you see some js error?

Comment: No, there are no js errors, just some warnings because of css sheets.

Comment: Is the action menu missing from all content types or just some? Is is missing from both View and Contents views? Do you have special browser views or extra Plone products installed?

Comment: It's missing from all content types and from the View and Contents views. I have several products installed, but even when I deactivate all of them, it's still missing. Changing the theme doesn't help either.

Comment: Just to shrink the problem: Did you already try with another user? Is the menu disappeared after a buildout re-run (maybe for an add-on installation) or  one day is simply disappeared? Another test could be to create another vanilla plone and to compare actions in the zmi between your site and the new one.

Comment: Please double-check your Firebug console because it really seems like you have some broken Javascript, especially because the dl#plone-contentmenu-actions does render. BTW is it empty inside or does it include a UL with four LI (Cut, Copy, Delete, Rename)?

Comment: With a new account (which I then granted the rights) it's the same. On a different Plone instance it works, so it can't be my browser. In Firebug, my "contentActionMenus" has 4 <li>, which are workflow, factories, display and actions. All 4 have the class="actionMenu deactivated". Interestingly, all four action menus have their several <li> with their respective content. But the actions-actionmenu is missing the cut, copy, paste and delete. "Checkout" and "enable_slider" (from an addon) are existent. So... how do I get those actions back, and how can I change the actionmenu back to "enabled"?